# Ember data and metadata - accessing from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data, active-model-serializers

I'm trying to access metadata using Ember Data, using ActiveModelAdapter. If the controller is set up in the router with model:

```
App.ClaimsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  authRedirectable: true
  model: ->
    @store.findAll 'claim'
```

And the controller as a meta method as follows:

```
App.ClaimsIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  meta: (->
    @store.metadataFor('claim')
  ).property()
```

Then I can access the metadata in the index template:

```
{{meta.page}} {{meta.per_page}} {{meta.total_pages}}
```

But I needed to add filtering. So I changed the router to use `setupController`:

```
App.ClaimsIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  setupController: (controller, model) ->
    controller.loadClaims()
```

And in the controller added the loadClaim function:

```
App.ClaimsIndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  loadClaims: ->
    _filter = @get 'filter'
    _result = @store.find 'claim', {filter: _filter}
    @set 'model', _result
  filter: ''
  meta: (->
    @store.metadataFor('claim')
  ).property()
  actions:
    filterClaims: ->
      @loadClaims()
```

Now the metadata is no longer available. I've entered the context using a debugger and can't seem to get anything.

Is there a problem with sending a query to Ember Data? Is there a better way to do this?

Incidentally, the metadata is sent by the server as [suggested in the docs.](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/handling-metadata/)

I'm using Ember 1.6.1 and Ember data 1.0.0-beta.8.2a68c63a

Comment: Is your issue that you say `controller.loadClaims()` instead of `controller.send('loadClaims')`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Didn't change the behavior.

Answer (score 4):

You could try several different ways for getting metadata. I didn't write on coffee, so I'll try to describe solutions using javascript.

1. Declare meta property of ClaimsIndexController as depended on model.meta property: `meta: function() { return this.get('model.meta'); }.property('model.meta')`
2. Declare meta property as null and fulfill it later in `then` callback of filter request in loadClaims method:

   ```
   loadClaims: function () {
       var filteredClaims = this.store.find('claim', { filter: this.get('filter') }),
           self = this;

       filteredClaims.then(function(claims) {
           self.set('meta', claims.get('meta'));
       });

       this.set('model', claims);
   }
   ```
3. As you can see, there is no need for method 'loadClaims', we can describe 'model' as computed property and set meta in here:

   ```
   model: function () {
       var filteredClaims = this.store.find('claim', { filter: this.get('filter') }),
           self = this;

       filteredClaims.then(function(claims) {
           self.set('meta', claims.get('meta'));
       });

       return filteredClaims;
   }.property('filter')
   ```
4. Or even simpler:

   ```
   model: function () {
      return this.store.find('claim', { filter: this.get('filter') });
   }.property('filter'),

   meta: function() {
      return this.get('model.meta');
   }.property('model.meta')
   ```
5. (questionable) In my opinion View (template) and data must be maximally separated, so I'd suggest to describe all metadata fields as computed properties of controller:

   ```
   model: function () {
      return this.store.find('claim', { filter: this.get('filter') });
   }.property('filter'),

   page: function() {
      return this.get('model.meta.page');
   }.property('model.meta.page'),

   perPage: function() {
      return this.get('model.meta.per_page');
   }.property('model.meta.per_page'),

   totalPages: function() {
      return this.get('model.meta.total_pages');
   }.property('model.meta.total_pages')
   ```

Comment: Great list of answers. I'm new to Ember and it really helps to see these iterations. I won't have time to test these for a day or two, but I will.

Comment: What is the proper way to access these in the view? So far I can't access the meta data from the view using `{{controller.meta.page}}` or `{{controller.page}}` or `{{page}}`.

Comment: If I access the store from the console I can retrieve the meta from the store using `store.metadataFor('claim')`, but so far I've not been able to get the meta through the model. The docs seem to suggest you can get the metadata through the results of `store.find`, but I've not been able to get anything. Any further thoughts?

Comment: `Ember.ActiveModelSerializer.extractMeta` method comes from `Ember.RESTSerializer` (https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.9/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/json_serializer.js#L944) and it receives meta data from playload.meta property. So, ember expects JSON like `{ meta: { ... }, claims: [ ... ] }` in response payload from store.find('claims') request. You can overload `extractMeta` meta, of course, and change it's behavior to suit other JSON schema.